# Search Criteria in Custom REST API

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom REST API that return all review of products based on store id.

```
http://hostname/magento/index.php/rest/V1/showreview/allreviews/1
```

it returns output like-

```
[{"review_id":"345","created_at":"2018-08-16 08:03:19","entity_id":"1","entity_pk_value":"1705","status_id":"1","detail_id":"345","title":"Huge arm holes??","detail":"I don't know why the arm holes are so big. It looked ok in the photo but in person they're really wide. It's really comfortable but that bugs me.","nickname":"Valorie","customer_id":null},{...}..]
```

Now my question is how to implement search criteria on custom rest api.?
actually i previously applied search criteria on predefined rest api but don't know how to implement on custom api.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: you can check magento CMS Page  `/V1/cmsPage/search`

Answer (score 4):

After lot of time spends,I solve my problem.
In url pass parameter as-

```
http://hostname/magento/index.php/rest/V1/showreview/allreviews/1?productId=1&title=value&....
```

now, in class where method is created use following code.
First use `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http` request and initialize in cosnstructor.

```
protected $request;
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request) {
       $this->request = $request;
    }
```

Then read all parameters from request.It returns an array of parameters.

```
//Get All parameters from request
        $allParameters=$this->request->getParams();
```

Then check each of parameters exist in url or not and apply filter using that parameters like-

```
if(array_key_exists("productId",$allParameters)){
                $collection=$collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_pk_value', ['eq' => $allParameters['productId']]);
             }
```

where $collection is contains all result where filter need to apply.

```
$collection = $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory")->create();
```